# Owin token call from angular 4 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin-middleware

I am using owin to generate oAuth token in asp.net webapi and I have added the UserCors as the 1st line in Configuration in Statrup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
}
```

I also added it again inside  ConfigureOAuth(app);

I manually tried to add header inside GrantResourceOwnerCredentials like below

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

But didn't works. I keep getting the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource from angular side.

When I add the headers in the config file it says duplicate.

```
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT,DELETE" />
</customHeaders>
```

Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Check what **header** you send. My header was content-type and had to add it to the **customheaders**. The header origin and methods has to match in the request and responce headers.

Comment: Can you please give me more details about the custom header? I am using 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to delete the Global.asax and call the WebApiConfig.Register from the startup file.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857438/bad-request-400-when-using-web-api-token-authenticaion-from-angualr-js/) helped me.